# Is EOF always negative?

Tags: c, eof

Is `EOF` always negative?

I'm thinking of writing a function that reads the next word in the input and returns the line number the word was found in or `EOF` if the end of the input has been reached. If `EOF` is not necessarily negative, the function would be incorrect.

Comment: Why do you even need to return EOF from your own function? Simply define your function as "returns the line number where the word was found, or -1 if the end of input was reached". That said, many sources (e.g. Code Complete) caution against mixing return values with failure codes.

Comment: Right, it's a possible and completely viable alternative. However, I thought EOF would have been more explicit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, EOF is always negative.

The Standard says:

> 7.19 Input/output 
>   7.19.1 Introduction
>
> 3 The macros are [...] EOF which
>   expands to an integer constant
>   expression, with type int and a
>   negative value, that is returned by
>   several functions to indicate
>   end-of-file, that is, no more input
>   from a stream;

Note that there's no problem with "plain" `char` being signed. The `<stdio.h>` functions which deal with `char`s, specifically cast the characters to `unsigned char` and then to `int`, so that all valid characters have a positive value. For example:

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream)
```

> 7.19.7.1
>   ... the fgetc function obtains that character as an unsigned char converted to an int ...

Comment: There is a problem if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, though as even the cast via `unsigned char` won't then necessarily keep all valid `char` values positive. Fortunately this is relatively rare.

Comment: That's only a problem if you wrongly assume a negative value is always EOF (`if (ch < 0) /* EOF detected */;`) or if the "execution character set" uses up all values from `INT_MIN` to `0` in which case the `EOF` value is the same as the value of a valid character.

Answer (score 16):

`EOF` is always `== EOF`. Don't assume anything else.

On a second reading of the standard (and as per some other comments here) it seems `EOF` is always negative - and for the use specified in this question (line number or `EOF`) it would work. What I meant to warn against (and still do) is assuming characters are positive and `EOF` is negative.

Remember that it's possible for a standard conforming C implementation to have negative character values - this is even mentioned in 'The C programming language' (K&R). Printing characters are always positive, but on some architectures (probably all ancient), control characters are negative. The C standard does not specify whether the `char` type is signed or unsigned, and the only character constant guaranteed to have the same value across platforms, is `'\0'`.

Comment: Could you add some references ?

Comment: This isn't correct. The EOF macro **must** expand to a negative integer, unfortunately I don't have my copy of the standard to hand at the moment.

Comment: The C Library Reference, which says that it takes nearly all of its information from the ANSI C Standard, says that "EOF is a negative integer which indicates an end-of-file has been reached" (http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#variables). That said, I would still say that it's bad style and, on top of that, unnecessary to assume EOF is negative.

Comment: Control characters are not usually negative. If your plain char type is signed and the code set is EBCDIC, then the value obtained by promoting the char value of 'A' (0xC1, 191) direct to int is negative; if you promote to unsigned char and then int, it will be positive, of course.

Comment: all members of the basic execution character set, however, are positive.

Comment: Detail: "the only character constant guaranteed to have the same value across platforms, is '\0'" --> `'\1'`, `'\2'`, `'\3'` ... `'\x1'`, `'\x2'`, have the same cross-platform value too as well as `L'...'`, `u'...'`, `U'...'` variants.

Answer (score 8):

Have that function return

- the line number the word was found in
- or -1 in case the end of the input has been reached

Problem solved, without a need for relying on any EOF values. The caller can easily test for greater-or-equal-to-zero for a successful call, and assume EOF/IO-error otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

From the [online draft n1256](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 17.9.1.3:

> **EOF**
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, 
>   that is returned by several functions to indicate *end-of-file*, that is, no more input
>   from a stream;

EOF is always negative, though it may not always be -1.

For issues like this, I prefer separating error conditions from data by returning an error code (`SUCCESS`, `END_OF_FILE`, `READ_ERROR`, etc.) as the function's return value, and then writing the data of interest to separate parameters, such as

```
int getNextWord (FILE *stream, char *buffer, size_t bufferSize, int *lineNumber)
{
  if (!fgets(buffer, bufferSize, stream))
  {
    if (feof(stream)) return END_OF_FILE; else return READ_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    // figure out the line number
    *lineNumber = ...;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EOF is a condition, rather than a value. The exact value of this sentinel is implementation defined. In a lot of cases, it is a negative number.

Comment: "In a lot of cases, it is a negative number." --> I'd suggest all cases as C does specify "EOF which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, ..."

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) :

> The actual value of EOF is a
>   system-dependent negative number,
>   commonly -1, which is guaranteed to be
>   unequal to any valid character code.

But no references ...

From Secure Coding : [Detect and handle input and output errors](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO04-C.+Detect+and+handle+input+and+output+errors)
EOF is negative but only when [sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO35-C.+Use+feof%28%29+and+ferror%28%29+to+detect+end-of-file+and+file+errors+when+sizeof%28int%29+%3D%3D+sizeof%28char%29).

Comment: Wikipedia isn't completely correct here. EOF could be -1, and with signed chars a character can have value -1 (e.g. The euro symbol in windows-1252). What is the case is that the return value of `(f)getc` is the next character cast to an unsigned char and then to an `int` and this shouldn't match `EOF`. Of course this can only work if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`.